# Primefaces ajax listener eclipse issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using jsf and primefaces to construct my page and am having an issue where the listener is not recognized. I am also using eclipse as IDE, in checking suggestions in writing code the method does not display.

it will say setter not found for property class.

short example:

-html

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myBean.value}" id="myID">
    <p:ajax event="click" update="form0" listener="#{myBean.listener}"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

-bean

```
  public void listener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
     //do something with event
    }
```

I can post all relevant code if needed. However, this is all the relevant information I feel is needed.

Comment: Language is IDE independent. Can you show us the annotations on your Bean and does value have setters/getters?

Comment: Did you try JBossTools extension? It has autocompleate capability.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the selectBooleanCheckbox don't have the evenet click.

Try changing

```
<p:ajax event="click" update="form0" listener="#{myBean.listener}"/>
```

By

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="form0" listener="#{myBean.listener}"/>
```